# C++ Class design problem. Associating class with other classes and quantity

Tags: c++, object, class-design

I have the following Material classes to be used by the BlockTest class.  The Material class itself will never be used and only serves to provide an interface for all child classes to implement.  Therefore the Material class could potentially be an abstract class.

```
class Material {
public:
    Material() : m_nQuantity(0) {}
    Material(uint8_t amount) : m_nQuantity(amount) {}
    virtual ~Material() {}

    virtual Vector2D* getTextureTop() {
        static Vector2D vector(0.0f, 0.0f);
        return &vector;
    }

    virtual uint16_t getMaterialId() {
        return 0;
    }

    uint8_t getQuantity() {
        return m_nQuantity;
    }

    uint8_t m_nQuantity;
};

class GrassMaterial : public Material {
public:
    GrassMaterial () : m_nQuantity(0) {}
    GrassMaterial (uint8_t amount) : Material(amount) {}
    virtual ~GrassMaterial () {}

    virtual Vector2D* getTextureTop() {
        static Vector2D vector(0.5f, 0.5f);
        return &vector;
    }

    virtual uint16_t getMaterialId() {
        return GRASS_BLOCK_ID;
    }

    uint8_t getQuantity() {
        return m_nQuantity;
    }
};
```

The Block class would need to have a reference to up to 4 different Material child classes which will be different for each instance of the Block class.

```
class BlockTest {
public:

    void render() {
        std::cout << "BlockTest(Material&& m1, Material&& m2)" << std::endl;
        std::cout << m_m[0].getTextureTop()->m_x << ":" << m_m[0].getTextureTop()->m_y << std::endl;
        std::cout << (int)m_m[0].getQuantity() << std::endl;

        std::cout << m_m[1].getTextureTop()->m_x << ":" << m_m[1].getTextureTop()->m_y << std::endl;
        std::cout << (int)m_m[1].getQuantity() << std::endl;
    }

    BlockTest() {}
    BlockTest(const BlockTest &obj) = delete;
    ~BlockTest() {
        m_m[0].m_nQuantity = 255;
        m_m[1].m_nQuantity = 255;
    }

    Material m_m[4];
};
```

Usage:

```
BlockTest* bt = new BlockTest();
Material* m1 = new (&(b1->m_m[0])) GrassMaterial(54);
Material* m2 = new (&(b1->m_m[0])) StoneMaterial(84);
```

Above is one way I found to achieve the desired behavior however it feels like really really bad code, also I'm not sure what the performance of the placement new operator is compared to stack allocation.

The performance is critical as I may be creating ~840 million BlockTest objects over a span of around 10 seconds which is why I cannot just have a Material* array on each class and constructing each material with the new operator.

The BlockTest objects have their memory pre-allocated in chunks of 65,536 and then constructed using placement new operator to minimise heap allocation costs and this doesn't cause any performance issues itself.

**What I actually need to happen.**

The Material child classes specify constant data that varies for each type of Material (Essentially texture UV maps, MATERIAL_ID, etc) so these variables can be static and just accessed via static methods without any need to instantiate an instance with no memory overhead.  However for each BlockTest class it also needs to associate each Material child class that it is composed of (between 1 and 4 different materials) with a quantity.

For example:
BlockTest* b1 consists of 3 Materials.

- GrassMaterial with a quantity of 50.
- StoneMaterial with a quantity of 155.
- IronMaterial with a quantity of 50.

BlockTest* b2 consists of 2 Materials.

- GrassMaterial with a quantity of 90.
- SandMaterial with a quantity of 165.

For each BlockTest instance it will need to access the static methods of each Material it contains (Methods always the same and defined in Material base class) and it will need a way to associate each of those materials with its quantity.

I figure that templates might be a better way to approach this however I'm not sure how to approach associating each template class with a quantity.  Also if the BlockTest class is templated I need a way to store an array of BlockTest* objects with all having different template arguments.

Comment: Using placement new to construct a derived class from a fully-constructed base class is undefined behavior, and will only end in tears. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Could you add a function to the block itself to create its required materials? This could potentially even be behaviour in the constructor. Then you could access the quantity from a static value within the constructor.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Is there anywhere I can read more about that?  I figured if the derived classes had any additional data members then it would be a big issue but it seems to work okay.  But definitely agree it's a bad idea.

Comment: @lennarthautzer can you think of a way to achieve that without heap allocation using the new operator and when the Material child classes are unknown and all unique?

Comment: There's nothing "to read more" about this, precisely because it is undefined behavior. It is not defined anywhere in the C++ standard, by definition. The closest to a real solution here, that ticks off all the checkmarks, is to use C++17's `std::variant`.